# NextJs: Static export with dynamic routes

Tags: next.js, netlify

I am a bit confused by the documentation and not sure if it's possible what I am trying to do.

Goal:

- Export NextJS app statically and host it on netlify
- Allow users to create posts and have links to these posts which work

For example:

- User creates a new post with the id: 2
- This post should be publicly accessible under `mysite.com/posts/2`

I'd imagine that I can create a skeleton html file called `posts.html` and netlify redirects all `posts/<id>` requests to that `posts.html` file which will then show the skeleton and load the necessary data via an API on the fly.

I think without this netlify hack, my goal of static export + working links to dynamic routes is not possible with next.js according to their [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) since `fallback: true` is only possible when using SSR.

Question: How can I achieve my dream setup of static nextjs export + working links to dynamic routes?

EDIT:
I just found out about [Redirects](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/#syntax-for-the-redirects-file). They could be the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### **getStaticProps** and **getStaticPaths()**

It looks like using **getStaticProps** and **getStaticPaths()** is the way to go.

I have something like this in my `[post].js` file:

```js
const Post = ({ pageContent }) => {
  // ...
}

export default Post;

export async function getStaticProps({ params: { post } }) {
  const [pageContent] = await Promise.all([getBlogPostContent(post)]);
  return { props: { pageContent } };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const [posts] = await Promise.all([getAllBlogPostEntries()]);

  const paths = posts.entries.map((c) => {
    return { params: { post: c.route } }; // Route is something like "this-is-my-post"
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

In my case, I query Contentful using my `getAllBlogPostEntries` for the blog entries. That creates the files, something like `this-is-my-post.html`. `getBlogPostContent(post)` will grab the content for the specific file.

```js
export async function getAllBlogPostEntries() {
  const posts = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: 'blogPost',
    order: 'fields.date',
  });
  return posts;
}

export async function getBlogPostContent(route) {
  const post = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: 'blogPost',
    'fields.route': route,
  });
  return post;
}
```

When I do an `npm run export` it creates a file for each blog post...

```
info  - Collecting page data ...[
  {
    params: { post: 'my-first-post' }
  },
  {
    params: { post: 'another-post' }
  },
```

In your case the `route` would just be 1, 2, 3, etc.

---

### Outdated Method - Run a Query in next.config.js

If you are looking to create a static site you would need to query the posts ahead of time, before the `next export`.

Here is an example using Contentful which you might have set up with blog posts:

First create a page under `pages/blog/[post].js`.

Next can use an `exportMap` inside `next.config.js`.

```js
// next.config.js
const contentful = require('contentful');

// Connects to Contentful
const contentfulClient = async () => {
  const client = await contentful.createClient({
    space: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  });
  return client;
};

// Gets all of the blog posts
const getBlogPostEntries = async (client) => {
  const entries = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: 'blogPost',
    order: 'fields.date',
  });
  return entries;
};

module.exports = {
  async exportPathMap() {
    const routes = {
      '/': { page: '/' }, // Index page
      '/blog/index': { page: '/blog' }, // Blog page
    };

    const client = await contentfulClient();
    const posts = await getBlogPostEntries(client);

    // See explanation below
    posts.items.forEach((item) => {
      routes[`/blog/${item.fields.route}`] = { page: '/blog/[post]' };
    });

    return routes;
  },
};
```

Just above `return routes;` I'm connecting to Contentful, and grabbing all of the blog posts. In this case each post has a value I've defined called route. I've given every piece of content a route value, something like `this-is-my-first-post` and `just-started-blogging`. In the end, the route object looks something like this:

```js
routes = {
  '/': { page: '/' }, // Index page
  '/blog/index': { page: '/blog' }, // Blog page
  '/blog/this-is-my-first-post': { page: '/blog/[post]' },
  '/blog/just-started-blogging': { page: '/blog/[post]' },
};
```

Your export in the `out/` directory will be:

```
out/
   /index.html
   /blog/index.html
   /blog/this-is-my-first-post.html
   /blog/just-started-blogging.html
```

In your case, if you are using post id numbers, you would have to fetch the blog posts and do something like:

```js
const posts = await getAllPosts();

posts.forEach((post) => {
  routes[`/blog/${post.id}`] = { page: '/blog/[post]' };
});

// Routes end up like
// routes = {
//   '/': { page: '/' }, // Index page
//   '/blog/index': { page: '/blog' }, // Blog page
//   '/blog/1': { page: '/blog/[post]' },
//   '/blog/2': { page: '/blog/[post]' },
// };
```

The next step would be to create some sort of hook on Netlify to trigger a static site build when the user creates content.

Also here is and idea of what your `pages/blog/[post].js` would look like.

```js
import Head from 'next/head';

export async function getBlogPostContent(route) {
  const post = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: 'blogPost',
    'fields.route': route,
  });
  return post;
}

const Post = (props) => {
  const { title, content } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{title}</title>
      </Head>
      {content}
    </>
  );
};

Post.getInitialProps = async ({ asPath }) => {
  // asPath is something like `/blog/this-is-my-first-post`
  const pageContent = await getBlogPostContent(asPath.replace('/blog/', ''));
  const { items } = pageContent;
  const { title, content } = items[0].fields;
  return { title, content };
};

export default Post;
```

Comment: Does this work for blog posts created after npm run export is run? I'm trying to get something working where users create bookings separate to me exporting and deploying.

Comment: Based on the documentation, I understand that when using the static export feature from next, you're limited to dynamic routes using `getStaticPaths` which is determines the available pages at **build time** and not at runtime. Therefore, you wouldn't be able to route to a blog post that was created after you built your next app. You would have to re-build your next app so that `getStaticPaths` picks up the new post and generates the static site for it which seems like a major drawback of using the static export feature together with dynamic routing...

Comment: As far as I know, @Ynnckth is right. But I don't understand why NextJS doesn't support loading data dynamically in a statically exported app, because HTML files can run JavaScript, which can call APIs etc. I'm trying to read stock tickers from a list in the browser's IndexedDB and route to a page to register transactions on a stock from that list. Then the Transactions page will need the ticker in it's dynamic route, which means reading a value from the URI. That should be possible with pure HTML and JavaScript.