# getServerSideProps does not render dynamic pages in production, and show 404 error

Tags: next.js, http-status-code-404, server-side-rendering, dynamic-routing, getserversideprops

I'm working with next.js, in development mode everything works fine, but in production mode I have a problem when rendering the pages dynamically.
I have the following path inside the pages folder
 `pages/user/[id]`, and this component is where I call the getServerSideProps function.

```js
import headers from '../../headers';

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

  const URL = 'https://somewhere...';

  let { id } = context.params;

  const apiResponse = await fetch(
    `${URL}/${id}/detail`,
    {
      headers: headers,
    }
  ); 
  if (apiResponse.ok) {
    
    const data = await apiResponse.json();
    return {
      props: data, // will be passed to the page component as props
    };
  } else {   
    return { props: {} };
  }
  
}
```

My problem is the following, I need to send in `headers` the authentication token that I only get when I login and I get the 2FA code, so in `build` time, that info does not exist and I get a 401 error no authorizate when execute `npm run build` and when I access to `/user/34` for example I get a 404 error.

I have checked these questions at stackoverflow:

- [NextJs: Static export with dynamic routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63673235/nextjs-static-export-with-dynamic-routes)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61724368/what-is-the-difference-between-next-export-and-next-build-in-next-js#:~:text=After%20building%2C%20next%20start%20starts,can%20serve%20with%20any%20host.&text=js%20will%20hydrate%20your%20application,to%20give%20it%20full%20interactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61724368/what-is-the-difference-between-next-export-and-next-build-in-next-js#:%7E:text=After%20building%2C%20next%20start%20starts,can%20serve%20with%20any%20host.&text=js%20will%20hydrate%20your%20application,to%20give%20it%20full%20interactivity).
- [next.js getStaticPaths list every path or only those in the immediate vicinity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62057131/next-js-getstaticpaths-list-every-path-or-only-those-in-the-immediate-vicinity)

I have some parts in my app that are statics and works fine, but the problem is with the dynamic paths, as next.js is not creating those paths.

EDIT: I'll include a image with other problem, if after the fetch in the if I just say :

```
if(apiResponse){ //without 'ok'

}
```

I'll recieve this errror:
[image: response error]

Comment: Where's `headers` coming from in your code? Also, `getServerSideProps` doesn't get called at build-time, it's called on each request to the page.

Comment: ```headers``` are imported from other file and it's working fine, and if  ```getServerSideProps``` it`s called on each request I always recieve a 404 response and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
return {
      props: data, // will be passed to the page component as props
    }
```

props should be object

```
return {
          props: {data} // or props: {data:data}
        }
```

Comment: I did that change too, finally we change a server with node.js and no continue usin nginx server and everything is working fine. I really don't want to say that problem was the server nginx because I suppose it's possbile configure it but I don't know how to do it. In resume with a server based i node.js all is working.